# Как побороть блокировку MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Добрый день!

Есть простая хранимая процедура - находим случайный счет у которого `Session_Id` равно `null`, и его резервируем, записывая туда `uid`:

```
begin try
   begin transaction
   select @Neg_Id=n1.Negotiation_Id from Negotiations n1 where
     n1.Session_Id is null and n1.Holder_Id=@HolderId and 
     n1.Negotiation_Status=1 order by dbo.i_now();
   if @Neg_Id=null
     throw 53001, 'Не удалось найти свободного счета', 1
   update  Negotiations set Session_Id = @SessionId where Negotiation_Id=@Neg_Id;
   if @@ROWCOUNT=0 throw 53002, 'Не удалось зарезервировать счет', 2;
   commit;
 end try
begin catch
  rollback transaction
  throw;
end catch;
```

При параллельном запуске с 6-и машин и выполнении этой хранимой процедуры с интервалом 3-5 секунд, через минут 5 получаю тупиковую блокировку:

> Transaction (Process ID хх) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.

Как побороть?

Comment: Из непонятного — `n1.Negotiation_Status=1 and n1.Negotiation_Status=bt.Bill_Type` что за алиас `bt` и зачем вообще второе сравнение? Стоит добавить в `SELECT` выборку одной строки `TOP (1)`, не думаю что вы пытаетесь перебрать все свободные `Negotiation_Id`.

Comment: Просто сначала проверяйте, есть ли "пустые" записи, если нет - огорчите юзера, а если есть, то просто пробуйте обновить ОДНУ запись, у которой Session_Id IS NULL, записывая туда свой ID, а потом SELECT-ом проверяйте, получилось или нет. Если вернулась запись - она твоя, если нет - значит, кто-то успел её прихватизировать, и надо всё повторить, включая проверку на существование незанятой записи. И транзакция вроде не нужна будет...

Comment: bt.Bill_Type - остаток от полного запроса, там соединение двух таблиц.

Comment: Пустые записи точно есть. Насчет Top 1 - понял.

Comment: Еще не понятно, зачем вам при `SELECT` использовать транзакцию. Откатывать ведь нечего в этом случае.

Comment: @vikolyada вы точно запрос целиком прочитали?

Comment: @PavelMayorov да пропустил `UPDATE`.

Comment: begin transaction поставил перед update, поставил TOP 1. Ситуация не изменилась

Comment: @DevMSSQLMoscow в таблице `Negotiations` всегда `Session_Id` в случае 'Holder_Id=@HolderId and Negotiation_Status=1' уникален?

Comment: В общем случае нет, но на дпнном этапе - да. Один пользователь может занять несколько счетов, тогда будет не уникален

Comment: @АлексейМайборода используйте один аккаунт - и не будете сталкиваться с ограничениями на комментирование из-за низкой репутации

Comment: Еще вопросы: 1. Сколько записей в таблице? 2. Сколько времени занимает ваш `SELECT`?

Comment: Счетов не много - около 20к, запрос - быстро: 0-0.015

Comment: @АлексейМайборода вы продолжнаете отвечать не с того аккаунта, с которого задали вопрос. вы не против, если я солью две учетных записи в одну?

Comment: Можете объединить

Answer (score 1):

Не разделяйте `SELECT` и `UPDATE` и уберите ручное управление транзакциями, примерно так:

```
declare @ids table (id int);

;with recordToUpdate as (
  select top 1 * from Negotiations n1 where
  n1.Session_Id is null and n1.Holder_Id=@HolderId and 
  n1.Negotiation_Status=1 order by dbo.i_now()
)
update recordToUpdate
set Session_Id = @SessionId
output inserted.Negotiation_Id into @ids

if @@ROWCOUNT=0 throw 53002, 'Не удалось зарезервировать счет', 2;

-- выбираем ID зарезервированной записи
select top 1 @Neg_Id = id from  @ids
```

...или явно пропишите `ROWLOCK, UPDLOCK, XLOCK` при `SELECT`, как вам посоветовали в соседнем ответе - тогда ваш `SELECT` будет выставлять локи так же, как `UPDATE`, и удерживать их до конца транзакции.

Но я бы на вашем месте выбрал вариант с одним апдейтом - совершенно непонятно, зачем разделять поиск свободной записи и ее резервирование.

Comment: Тогда уж так `UPDATE TOP (1) Negotiations SET Session_Id = @SessionId where n1.Session_Id is null and n1.Holder_Id=@HolderId and n1.Negotiation_Status=1 order by dbo.i_now();` Но насколько я понимаю, `@Neg_Id` надо вернуть пользователю.

Comment: @vikolyada не помню, можно ли делать update c orderby. при апдейте можно выбрать апдейтнутые строки, сейчас допишу

Comment: @vikolyada дописал выборку ID измененной записи

Comment: вы правы. Нельзя делать `update`с `order by`. Ваше решение лучше.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте такой вариант:

```
BEGIN TRY;
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    SELECT TOP (1)
      @Neg_Id = n1.Negotiation_Id
    FROM Negotiations n1 WITH(ROWLOCK, UPDLOCK) -- блокируем строку
    WHERE n1.Session_Id IS NULL
        AND n1.Holder_Id = @HolderId
        AND n1.Negotiation_Status = 1
    ORDER BY dbo.i_now();

    IF @Neg_Id = NULL
      THROW 53001, 'Не удалось найти свободного счета', 1;

   UPDATE Negotiations
    SET Session_Id = @SessionId
    WHERE Negotiation_Id = @Neg_Id;

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
      THROW 53002, 'Не удалось зарезервировать счет', 2; 

   COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH;
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    THROW;
END CATCH;
```

Comment: Не дает вписать XLOCK - Conflicting locking hints specified. Версия MSSQL 2014

Comment: @DevMSSQLMoscow да нужно оставить `XLOCK` или `UPDLOCK'.